# Sitecore web forms for marketers - how to create a custom validation?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I want to create a form with two controls(radio button and file upload), with Web Forms for Marketers in Sitecore.
Something like this:

- Yes
- No

(File Upload here) (Browse button here)

If the user checks Yes radio button, the file upload will become mandatory. Otherwise it's not a mandatory field.

How do I make this possible? The Sitecore documentation only has very limited information. I was trying to create a user control and implement validate user control class, but I was stuck because have no idea with the functions I need to override.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience with custom actions on Webforms for Marketeers forms I would say this would typically be a use case in which you should develop your own form and not use Webforms for Marketeers functionality. With alot of coding / configuring you should probably in the end be able to set it up like the description you give, but I think you would be better of creating a form yourself in this scenario. I have been able to do alot with Webforms but there certainly are some constraints eventhough alot is possible.